# How to get chi-square p-value from gofstat in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I'm trying to compare sample data with lists of distributions (thanks to help on StackOverflow), but have hit a bit of a roadblock. gofstat seems to be working splendidly, and the graphical output is exactly what is desired. However, the final point of this piece of code is to find the most fitting distribution to the sample data (which will eventually be read from a text file, and will not be ideal at all), and the parameters of said distribution.

The first step for me is to find the appropriate p-value for the chi-square test statistic for each distribution and the data, and then find the largest of these p-values, which should indicate the most fitting distribution. However, I can't seem to get proper output from the code. Whenever I run the code below, I receive a NULL output (twice, because of the loop in the code). According to documentation, this is the output when the test statistic is not calculated. How do I get gofstat to calculate it, and display the p-value? (and the distribution parameters, if possible)

```
library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(1)
testData <- lnorm(1000)
distlist <- c("norm","unif")

# Loop through list of distributions
for(i in 1:length(distlist)){
  x <- fitdist(testData, distlist[i])
  gofstat(x)
  print(x$chisqpvalue)
  plot(x)
}
```

Comment: My fear in giving advice for automated methods for fitting distributions is that the next steps will be  what you are proposing. If there is no science behind what you are doing then choosing distributions this way seems rather pointless. Seems like using the empirical function would be more appropriate.

Comment: The next steps will be to export the fitted distribution as a function with its parameters to text file, and model the function as an entity in a generic simulation package.